# RubyGem Environment incorrect (gem env)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, rubygems

So I'm following a book and installed GIT, CURL, rvm, RubyGems, and ruby.

When I run gem env, the variables incorrect... my home is "/home/wegener" NOT "/home/wegejos" ... I have no clue where or how it got the incorrect home world... I used rvm to install RubyGems and Ruby.

```
[~]$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/wegejos/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/wegener/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/wegejos/ruby/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/wegejos/ruby/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/wegejos/ruby/gems"
     - "gempath" => []
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

.

```
[~]$ env
reinstall_flag=1
rvm_bin_path=/home/wegener/.rvm/bin
HOSTNAME=ren.renegew.com
GEM_HOME=/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
IRBRC=/home/wegener/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc
SSH_CLIENT=24.8.185.82 51882 22
PERL5LIB=/home/wegener/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux:/home/wegener/perl5/lib/perl5
MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/wegener/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base /home/wegener/perl5
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=wegener
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.flac=01;35:*.mp3=01;35:*.mpc=01;35:*.ogg=01;35:*.wav=01;35:
__array_start=0
rvm_path=/home/wegener/.rvm
escape_flag=1
rvm_prefix=/home/wegener
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/wegener
PATH=/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/wegener/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/wegener/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/wegener/perl5/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/wegener/bin
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
PWD=/home/wegener
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk
uninstall_flag=1
EDITOR=pico
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
_second=1
rvm_version=1.13.6 (stable)
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/wegener
LS_OPTIONS=--color=tty -F -a -b -T 0
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/home/wegener/perl5
_first=0
LOGNAME=wegener
VISUAL=pico
CVS_RSH=ssh
GEM_PATH=/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jdk/lib/classes.zip
SSH_CONNECTION=24.8.185.82 51882 96.125.160.242 22
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
PROMPT_COMMAND=echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"
install_flag=1
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.3-p194
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/wegener/perl5
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/bin/env
```

Comment: Check your `$GEM_PATH` and `$GEM_HOME` environment variables.

Comment: `[~]$ echo $GEM_PATH; echo $GEM_HOME

/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
/home/wegener/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194`

Answer (score 2):

I found it! It was hidden in some file at /home/wegener/.gemrc ... I have no clue why it was set to wegejos or where that even came from.. there is not even a /home/wegejos/ I changed it to /home/wegener/ and now it's working.